# IBDesignable UIView with embedded UIButtons, how do I hook up actions in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, storyboard, ibdesignable

I'm trying to create a simple re-usable view for answering multiple choice questions for storyboards. In this custom IBDesignable view, there is a read only uitextview (for the question), several UIButtons representing the answers. I don't seem to find a way to be able to link the UIButtons to actions in the ViewController this view is embedded (via a custom view). Is this possible at all? Or should this be considered a custom UIControl?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at all (as of Xcode 8.3.2). You can only connect outlets and actions to the top-level `@IBDesignable` view, not to any of its subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can always connect it in code, for example

```
@IBOutlet weak var pitchView: PitchPanelView!
....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        pitchView.bassPitchSlider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(bassPitchSliderValueChanged(_ :)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

where pitchView is a custom IBDesignable view, and self is the ViewController where the pitchView is connected